# Undefined variable within a function

Tags: javascript

Look at the following snippet:

```
var fruit = "Orange";
echoThis();

function echoThis() {    
    alert(fruit);
    var fruit = "Apple";
}
```

When I run this snippet, the alert of `fruit` is `undefined`. Why?

First I thought it has something to do with hoisting, that within a funciton, the JS engine "lifts" all `var` declarations to the top or something, but then I would expect the alert to display `Apple`, not `undefined`.

There's probably some elementary JS behaviour I'm unaware of. Anyone care to explain?

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z37230c9/

Comment: You have to pass fruit as an argument to the function. Or make your variable "fruit" public by removing the "var"

Comment: I know how I can get it to work. Now I'm just trying to figure out why it behaves this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).  Variables declared in a function are available for the entire scope, but they are assigned a value where you put it.

This:

```
function echoThis() {    
    alert(fruit);
    var fruit = "Apple";
}
```

becomes this:

```
function echoThis() {    
   var fruit;
   alert(fruit);
   fruit = "Apple";
}
```

This is why you code is evaluated successfully, but fruit's value is undefined.

also:

```
var fruit = "Orange"; //this fruit variable
echoThis();

function echoThis() {    
    alert(fruit);
    var fruit = "Apple"; // is overridden by this, 
     //because it's re-declared in a local scope. 
}
```

if you really want to change this then remove the `var` in the function.

```
   function echoThis() {    
        alert(fruit);
        fruit = "Apple";  //this now accesses the global fruit.
    }
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I wasn't trying to accomplish anything particular except learning JS behaviour here. So basically the answer to my question is: Var declarations are hoisted, but variable assignments are not?

Comment: Additionally, function declarations will be fully hoisted; function expressions, just the variable name (as above).

Answer (score 3):

The variable is hoisted to the top of the function when it is compiled.

```
function echoThis() {    
    alert(fruit);
    var fruit = "Apple";
}

Translates to this

function echoThis() {    
    var fruit;
    alert(fruit);
    fruit = "Apple";
}
```

So when the alert is called it is technically undefined at this point.
 To stop seeing that move your variable declaration before the alert statement.

Comment: Allright, but why is only "var fruit" hoisted, and not "var fruit = "Apple"?

Comment: Only variable declarations are hoisted, but not the assignments.. that is how the compiler works

Comment: @Weblurk Because only declarations are hoisted, not asignments.

Comment: @Cristy Gotcha, makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

that's because js has lexical scope and hoisting.

so `echoThis` looks for `fruit` within itself before looking outside and since you  have `var fruit = "Apple";` , `fruit` is hoisted in `echoThis`.

Comment: I don't think lexical scope has anything to do with this. http://pierrespring.com/2010/05/11/function-scope-and-lexical-scoping/

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above responses, if you want to get the orange AND the apple after.. you could try to pass the variable simply as a parameter and work in the function

```js
var fruit = "Orange"; 
echoThis(fruit);

function echoThis(fruit) {
  alert(fruit); // You will get the orange
  var fruit = "Apple";
  alert(fruit); // You will get the apple
}
```